# VBA and Java Webservice

Tags: java, vba, excel

I have implemented a WebService in Java (RMI). In Excel I have two Makros, the one reads Data from the database via the webservice. the other writes to the database.

Reading the data from the database over the webservice is no problem (function: `MyData[] getData() {...}`)
but when i try to call the method, which should write data to the database I have the problem, that the given Data from the VBA-Code is null then in the Java-Code.

Function:  `public void setData(final MyData[]) {...}`

I debugged and found out, that the parameter isn't null in the VBA Code. It's only null in the Java Code.

So does anybody know, where the data may be lost?

I thought maybe I have a problem with the XML or the like, but I really don't know where to look for the mistake.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: I will show you the code as soon as possible, but I have to wait some hours to be able to comment in a proper way, because I'm a new one here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Of course: here is the code - I shortened it a little bit, but the main functionality is given

Btw, I changed the type of the data now to long and now I get an `IllegalArgumentException`

Java:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "setData", action = "setData")
    public void setData(final long k)
    {
        myValue = k;
    }
```

VBA
in Sheet1 I call e.g.:

```
Call dataService.wsm_setData(5)
```

and in the serviceFile (generated with Web Service Toolkit):

```
Private sc_DataServic As SoapClient30
Private Const c_WSDL_URL As String = "http://pcname:8010/myurl/data?wsdl"
Private Const c_SERVICE As String = "DataServiceService"
Private Const c_PORT As String = "DataServicePort"
Private Const c_SERVICE_NAMESPACE As String = "http://myurl"

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set sc_DataServic = New SoapClient30
   sc_DataServic.MSSoapInit2 c_WSDL_URL, str_WSML, c_SERVICE, c_PORT, c_SERVICE_NAMESPACE
    sc_DataServic.ConnectorProperty("ProxyServer") = "<CURRENT_USER>" 
    sc_DataServic.ConnectorProperty("EnableAutoProxy") = True
    Set sc_DataServic.ClientProperty("GCTMObjectFactory") = New clsof_Factory_Data
End Sub

Public Function wsm_setData(ByVal dcml_arg0 As Double)

    On Error GoTo wsm_setDataTrap

    sc_DataServic.setData dcml_arg0

    Set sc_DataServic = Nothing
Exit Function
wsm_setDataTrap:
    DataServicErrorHandler "wsm_setData"
End Function
```